# How to best automate a repetitive Unity workflow

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a unity workflow wherein I am trying to render several video recordings of a 3D model speaking out certain words. I have a large list of words for this purpose, along with the corresponding information required to articulate those words using the [LipSync Pro asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/lipsync-pro-32117). My workflow involves basically creating an asset from LipSync by selecting an audio file and the accompanying xml phone sequence, and then using this bundled asset inside LipSync. This is followed by entering play mode to create a rendering of a 3D model speaking that word which I want to record.

I will need to repeat this process efficiently for a large number of cases in order to generate *k* number of video clips for *k* words. I was unable to find any equivalent of an editor macro system, nor a selenium like way of controlling the UI from an external program. What is the recommended approach to accomplish this? Any pointers in the right direction would be brilliant as I am quite new to the framework.

Comment: You could probably use something like [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/) or similar Job-Pipeline based tool, configure your required steps and automate the entire thing. In particular for Unity things like importing assets, entering playmode and render stuff could all be done via Editor scripts and the [command line arguments](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html) .. so basically you are creating a batch script which could either do one or the entire list automated and even unintended over night, however there is of course also quite a configuration overhead before it runs

Comment: Don't know how exactly LipSync works and if it can be done all via command line, if so then yes you could simply create a batch process